# Is there a way to connect to hotspot automatically in mac if wifi is not working?

Tags: macbook-pro, network, wifi, ventura, tethering

Is there a seamless way to connect to the hotspot network automatically in mac if the wifi network is not working?

I am doing it manually. Is there a way to do it automatically in a seamless fashion?

I am using macbook pro and Ventura 13.5.